# Why are models having there parent class names in admin Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users, django-admin-actions

I have created models like this

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Supplier(User):
    company_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_domain=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    

class Worker(User):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Regular'),
    )
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)
```

and in the  users.admin.py,  I have

```
admin.site.register(Supplier)
admin.site.register(Worker)
```

Why is it that I have all models names as Users in the Django Admin? instead of Workers and Suppliers?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `AbstractUser` is an abstract model it's `Meta` class is inherited by all subclasses, [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).

You need to provide your own `Meta` class for each model and pass the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` attributes to override the values set in `AbstractUser`s `Meta` class

```
class Supplier(User):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_domain = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'supplier'
        verbose_name_plural = 'suppliers'


class Worker(User):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Regular'),
    )
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'worker'
        verbose_name_plural = 'workers'
```

Answer (score 0):

They are probably taking the verbose name of User's class since both inherit from it.
Try to modify like this:

```py
class Supplier(User):
    company_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_domain=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = 'Supplier'

class Worker(User):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Regular'),
    )
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = 'Worker'
```

I got it from this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/customize-django-admin-interface/).